# In the multivariate case, does an integrable characteristic function implies a continuous density function?

Tags: probability, continuity, density-function, characteristic-functions

In the univariate case, it is easy to see that if the characteristic function $\phi$ of a $\mathbb R$-random variable $X$ is integrable, then by the inversion theorem the p.d.f $f$ of $X$ is continuous. 
Does this result still hold for $X$ in $\mathbb R^d$, $d\geq2$ ?

Comment: Yes, there is an inversion theorem in the multivariate case also  and you do get continuous density.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reference ? I have been browsing the internet for hours unsuccessfully...

Comment: It is consequence of Fourier inversion theorem in $\mathbb R^{n}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem